# Filter out duplicate results in where clause in sql server

Tags: oracle

select * from user where username is equal to 'jw'

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT DISTINCT ...` ?

Comment: different employee id's can have the same memb_id?

Comment: No, the `DISTINCT` keyword has to follow `SELECT` directly.

Comment: if you could show an example of what the duplicate data would look like that might be helpful

Comment: No, each Memb_id is assigned to a unique employee. they have a 1 to 1 relationship. here is an example:  WorkId EmployeeId MembId  501986 110629 2079277  502178 110629 2079541  
502195 110629 2079541

Comment: I dont know how to show it as a grid in comment

Comment: Edit your question to add sample data. Is this for SQL Server or Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Add `DISTINCT` directly after `SELECT`, or alternatively, use the GROUP BY clause after your WHERE clause.

ex: `GROUP BY works.memb_id`

Comment: DISTINCT does't work on this case. That was the first thing I tries and for GROUP BY , here is the error: Column 'CARS.DBO.WORK_Worksheets.WORK_ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are trying to do.  WorkID, EmployeeID, and MembID all have to be 1:1 and then you want to group on all three fields.

You have asserted that each Memb_id is assigned to a unique employee.  If WorkID is not then you will need to use an aggregate function to select one of the records returned after the group.  Such as Min(), Max() or a window function like Row_Number and or Rank.

For example

```
WorkID, EmployeeID, MembID
1  1  1
2  1  1
3  2  2
4  1  1
```

If you use Min(WorkID), EmployeeID, MembID....Group By EmployeeID, MembID you will get:

```
WorkID, EmployeeID, MembID
1  1  1
3  2  2
```

If this is not what you are looking for some sample data as a whole and what results you expect would be necessary.

Comment: I doesn't work may be this screen shot helps: if you look at the image I uploaded here http://s32.postimg.org/9j71nvrad/image.jpg , I have multiple membId with id = 2079541 , I should show only 1 and not show the duplicates.

Comment: Is the image you uploaded from @WALKINS or from cars.dbo.work.worksheets?

Comment: P.Salmon asked a good question.  If my answer is not working I would need more info, specifically a sample of the data in cars.dbo.work.worksheets and how you want the data to look afterwards.  I am not sure what the image represents.